# Why do I not see the tasks in the my tasks view on the tasks list?

Tags: tasks, view

I am using SharePoint 2013. Out of the box I have a task list. In this task list there are out of the box some views like "My Tasks". I have created some tasks which are assigned to some SharePoint usergroup. In this SharePoint group there are 3 users and also my user account.

When I go to the task view "my tasks"  I dont see this task! When I go another view like "all tasks" or "active tasks" I see the task.

Why I dont see this task in my view "my tasks"? Can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Tasks have filter set as "Assigned To"=[Me] , this will display only if you are directly added to the Assigned To columnn value NOT through any SharePoint Group. If you want My Tasks to show the tasks which are assigned to any group in which you belong you will have to modify the View using SharePoint Designer. Modify the caml query of the view and add extra check of whether current user belongs to group specified in the **Assigned To** column.Use the below code:

```
<Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">

       <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>

     </Membership>
```

Comment: Is it possible to set the caml query to filter the tasks directly assigned to me and assigned to my groups in the same time?
Something like: <Or><In><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" LookupId="TRUE"/><Values><Value Type="Integer"><UserID/></Value></Values></In><Membership Type="CurrentUserGroups"><FieldRef Name="AssignedTo"/></Membership></Or> 
But its not working for me...